# Uniqueness of infinite polynomial functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

This is not a homework question, it is just something I was wondering about.

Suppose we have 2 sequences of real numbers, ${a_i}$ and ${b_i}$, and their respective polynomials $A(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$ and $B(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k x^k$ both converging in some range $\Omega$.

It's pretty obvious that if $(\forall k) a_k = b_k$ then $(\forall x \in \Omega) A(x) = B(x)$.

But is it true that if $(\exists k) a_k \ne b_k$ then $(\exists x \in \Omega) A(x) \ne B(x)$ ?  Or to put it another way, do all functions have unique polynomials expansions?  For example, is there possibly an expansion of $e^x$ other than $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k / k!$?  What about a function that isn't differentiable everywhere, like a sawtooth function?

Thanks~

Comment: google "uniqueness of Taylor series"

Comment: By the way, we don't say "infinite polynomial," we say "power series." Purely to clarify - there are too many theorems about (finite) polynomials that are not true for power series, so we try to avoid having to say "finite" every time we are talking about polynomials.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's a nice and well reasoned convention, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: It's more than a convention - no mathematician calls a power series an "infinite polynomial."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is true. If a power series has radius of convergence >0, then it is infinitely differentiable in the same region and the coefficient
$a_n, n=1, 2, 3, ...$ of the series are given by
$$
a_n=f^{(n)}(0)/n!
$$
The property is most powerful property of analytic functions.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.  Can you please elaborate on the reason that the above sequence is the only possible sequence?  What if a function is discontinuous or not differential at certain points?